# Why won't NULL values return in a LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the below statement to return flow id counts for today's date, joined to another table so we can see a little more meta data. With the left join though, it's not showing all the hubs that *dont* have data for today. I'm assuming it may be because of the where clause, but not sure how to fix that. Suggestions?

```
   SELECT   O.DATE,
            R.HUB,
            COUNT (O.FLOWID) AS point_counts
    FROM    table_r R
            LEFT JOIN  table_o O ON O.FLOWID = R.FLOWID  
    WHERE   O.DATE = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
    GROUP BY O.DATE, R.HUB
    ORDER BY R.HUB
```

Comment: Because you're turning your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN` with your `WHERE` clause.  Move the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `where` condition to the `join` clause.

```
LEFT JOIN  table_o O ON O.FLOWID = R.FLOWID AND O.DATE = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using the filter: `O.DATE = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())`, essentially making it an `INNER JOIN`, since the filter is applied on a column from the outer table.

Comment: So is there a way to still effectively filter values on for today's date? Or no.

Comment: Today meaning CONVERT(date,GETDATE())

Comment: that depends on the result data that you want. If the date comes from the outer table and you want results just for today, then you are saying that every result must be in the outer table (there can't be `NULL`s)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are filtering the left joined table using the where clause. If you only want the left joined table to return rows where the date = today's date, `and o.date=convert(date,getdate())` after the on criteria of the join

Answer (score 0):

You may try to move the WHERE condition to JOIN, also remove `GROUP BY O.DATE`, as you filter DATE only today's date, it doesn't make sense to GROUP BY the DATE again

```
   SELECT   MAX(O.DATE),
            R.HUB,
            COUNT (O.FLOWID) AS point_counts
    FROM    table_r R
    LEFT JOIN  table_o O 
        ON O.FLOWID = R.FLOWID  
        AND O.DATE = CONVERT(date,GETDATE())
    GROUP BY R.HUB
    ORDER BY R.HUB
```